# How do I mock a a file IO so that I can override the name attribute in a unit test?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to write a unit test mock opening a file and passing it into a function that uses it to dump a JSON object into. How do I create a fake IO object that mimics the behavior of an open file handle but uses similar attributes, specifically `.name`?

I've read through tons of answers on here and all of them work around the problem in various ways. I've tried mock patching `builtins.open`, I've tried mock patching the `open` being called inside my module, but the main error I keep running into is that when I try to access the fake IO object's `.name` attribute, I get an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'CallbackStream' object has no attribute 'name'
```

So here's a simple function that writes a dictionary to disk in JSON format and takes an open file handle:

```
def generate(data, json_file):
  # data is a dict
  logging.info(f"Writing out spec file to {json_file.name}")
  json.dump(data, json_file)
```

Here's what I've tried to unit test:

```
    @patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open())
    def test_generate_json_returns_zero(self, mock_open):
        mocked_file = mock_open()
        mocked_file.name = "FakeFileName"
        data = {'stuff': 'stuff2'}
        generate(data, json_file=mocked_file)
```

However, that produces the AttributeError above, where I can't use `json_file.name` because it doesn't exist as an attribute. I thought setting it explicitly would work, but it didn't.

I can bypass the issue by using a temporary file, via `tempfile.TemporaryFile:

```
    def test_generate_json_returns_zero(self, mock_open):
        data = {'stuff': 'stuff2'}
        t = TemporaryFile("w")
        generate(data, json_file=t)
```

But that doesn't solve the *actual* problem, which is that I can't figure out how to mock the file handle so that I don't actually need to create a real file on disk.

I can't get past the `.name` not being a valid attribute. How do I mock the file object such that I could actually use the `.name` attribute of an IO object and still fake a `json.dump()` to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new_callable` parameter is meant to be an alternative class of `Mock`, so when you call:

```
@patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open())
```

It patches `builtins.open` by replacing it with what `mock_open()` returns, rather than a `MagicMock` object, which is what you actually need, so change the line to simply:

```
@patch("builtins.open")
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your test never actually calls `open`, so there's no need to patch it. Just create a `Mock` instance with the attribute you need.

```
def test_generate_json_returns_zero(self):
    mocked_file = Mock()
    mocked_file.name = "FakeFileName"
    data = {'stuff': 'stuff2'}
    generate(data, json_file=mocked_file)
```